# 'Var' does not name a type!

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, c++, error

I don't have much experience in C++ programming. I'm getting this error

`'z' does not name a type!!!`

which I have't seen in MATLAB or python... What's wrong??? It is so simple!!!

```
float x=10; float y=50; float z;
z=x*y;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

Comment: `float z=x*y;` will work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot put an expression statement outside a function. Only the variable declarations can be placed outside functions (and those variables are called globals/global variables).

Try the following:

```
float x=10; float y=50; float z;


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  z=x*y;
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

**Update**

What even is easier and also works (thanks to Ruslan and Juraj):

```
float x=10; float y=50; float z=x*y;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

Comment: Thank you. pretty much basic thing that I didn't know about C++.

Comment: You can put an _expression_ outside a function (e.g. `float z=x*y;` does have an expression `x*y` in it, and may appear in namespace scope). What you can't put there is an _expression statement_ (or any other type of statements).

Comment: @Ruslan Thanks for the clarification; I added the word statement in my answer.

Comment: and `float z=x*y;`